# Qt keep gui responsive

Tags: c++, qt, concurrency

In my application, when a button is clicked I need to do some long IO operations of around 10 seconds and show some data. I handle it like below:

```
class ResultType{ /* ... */ };

ResultType LongIOOperation() { /* ... */ }

auto MainWindow::DoLongIOOperation() -> ResultType
{
    QEventLoop eventLoop;

    auto watcher = QFutureWatcher<ResultType>{ this };

    connect(&watcher, &decltype(watcher)::finished,
        &eventLoop, &decltype(eventLoop)::quit);

    watcher.setFuture( QtConcurrent::run(LongIOOperation) );

    // Watcher intercepts the event loop when done
    eventLoop.exec();

    return watcher.future().result();
}
```

I got the idea from [here](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qq/qq27-responsive-guis.html). This is quite unwieldy. Requires lots of boiler-plate (especially if you need to do this exec()+quit() thing multiple times back to back for operations that need GUI access in between). I've also heard that it's inefficient and potentially dangerous. There has got to be an easier way. How do I do it? Perhaps C++20 coroutines could help?

Comment: Do you consider `QThread` to be "easier"?

Comment: @JarMan Possibly. What do you have in mind?

Comment: There are tons of examples on SO of pushing time-consuming operations onto a separate QThread. Then you just emit a signal when the operation is done.

Comment: @JarMan this function returns the result though. I guess you could send the result with a signal. Hmm. Handling the signal/slot connections might actually be more boiler-plate

Comment: There's plenty of boilerplate any way you choose.

Comment: @JarMan I guess you're right. I thought there could be a simpler method. Thank you for the help. If no one adds a better answer, I'll remove the question.

Comment: _I'll remove the question._ Alone the title and the link are worth to be kept (and found by future google searches) not to mention your sample code. (I spent an up-vote to make it not that easy...)

Comment: @Scheff thank you for that! Looks like the general advice is "pick your poison". I wonder how much of that will change with coroutines.